# Is there a way to edit or import List Items from/to a Combo Box in InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, workflow, interactive

I'm currently working on translating an interactive PDF in InDesign and I am wondering if there is a way to edit already written List Items instead of having to delete and adding new ones each time I want to edit the List.

Editing would be useful, but having the possibility of importing an already made list to the Combo Box would also work as well in my case, since I'm trying to change a month's list from one language to another and since it is repeated a lot, being able to import a list of the months in the correct language onto it would be useful and save time instead of having to rewrite them each time.

Are there any ways to do either of these things with Combo Boxes?

[image: Combo box Buttons and Forms InDesign Panel]

Comment: I don't believe there is.